# Regex to check when a word pattern is missing from the string

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I have a target string something like this 
PT_content:data1 AND PT_content2:data2 OR PT_content3:data3

now i need to check whether any invalid qualifier is there in the string., 
For example

PT_content:data1 AND PR_content2:data2 OR PT_content3:data3(this is invalid as only **PT_xxxxxx:data** is allowed.)

I tried some pattern with negative lookahead, but it doesnt seem s to work

```
Pattern.compile("(?!.*PT_[a-zA-Z]*:)")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
^(?:PT_[a-zA-Z]*:[^ ]+ (?:AND|OR|$))+$
```

Answer (score 1):

```
^(PT_[a-z]*:data($| AND | OR ))+$
```

Given pattern matches multiple **PT_xxxxxx:data** followed by `AND`, `OR` or end of string. In this pattern can **xxxxxx** be anything from `''` to unlimited characters as long as it only consists of alpha's.

Is this what you're looking for are am I missing anything?

**EDIT**

Only alpha's are allowed as separators. This covers `AND` and `OR` too since it allows capitals.

```
^(PT_[a-z]*:data($| [a-zA-Z]* ))+$
```

Comment: It can be AND OR or some other thing xxxxx is [a-z]* actually.

Comment: You mean these values can be seperated by more than just ` AND ` or ` OR `? You should specify on which requirements these seperators will match.

Comment: Because you can't just replace the seperated with wildcards since this would bypass your negatives (being `PR_abc:data` for example).

Comment: Yes . they can be seperated by more values ,

Comment: As said, please specify to what these values will match, just alpha's, also numbers, how about dots or comma's et cetera. As previously mentioned, a wildcard can't be used to validate these separators.

Comment: @BijuCNair Updated accordingly ;) [Regex Tester](http://www.regexpal.com/) in case you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just to create "positive" pattern and try to match string using this pattern? If string *does not* match this is your case.

Comment: I dont know much about that.

Comment: Won't work. If you are matching a specific pattern and as part of the pattern a word must be missing, then including the word as being present and then doing the opposite of that pattern will indeed match the missing word, but will also no longer match the rest of the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether you really need lookahead or lookbehind here.

If your problem is with "PR_" instead of "PT_", try this:

```
String content = "PT_content:data1 AND PR_content2:data2 OR PT_content3:data3";
Pattern badSyntax = Pattern.compile("P[^T]_.*?:.*?\\s");
Matcher matcher = badSyntax.matcher(content);
while (matcher.find()) System.out.println(matcher.group());
```

Output:

```
PR_content2:data2
```

Comment: Hi Mena . Sorry IT can be anything , not just **PT**